# How to match alphabetical chars without numeric chars with Python regexp?

Tags: python, regex

Using Python module re, how to get the equivalent of the "\w" (which matches alphanumeric chars) WITHOUT matching the numeric characters (those which can be matched by "[0-9]")?

Notice that the basic need is to match any character (including all unicode variation) without numerical chars (which are matched by "[0-9]").

As a final note, I really need a regexp as it is part of a greater regexp.

Underscores should not be matched.

EDIT:

- I hadn't thought about underscores state, so thanks for warnings about this being matched by "\w" and for the elected solution that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want `[^\W\d]`: the group of characters that is not (either a digit or not an alphanumeric). Add an underscore in that negated set if you don't want them either.

A bit twisted, if you ask me, but it works. Should be faster than the lookahead alternative.

Comment: Nice, +1 from me. Didn't think of that one.

Comment: great idea, that can be re-used with other patterns and other regex implementation.

Answer (score 9):

```
(?!\d)\w
```

A position that is not followed by a digit, and then `\w`. Effectively cancels out digits but allows the `\w` range by using a negative look-ahead.

The same could be expressed as a positive look-ahead and `\D`:

```
(?=\D)\w
```

To match multiple of these, enclose in parens:

```
(?:(?!\d)\w)+
```

Comment: Don't forget that \w also contains the underscore.

Comment: The OP did say nothing about the underscore. How is that relevant?

Comment: Just in case the OP doesn't expect it. I like your solution.