# How to match all unicode alphabetic characters and spaces in a regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, unicode, django-forms

I am trying to validate place names in python 3/ django forms. I want to get matches with strings like: `Los Angeles`, `Canada`, `中国`, and `Россия`. That is, the string contains:

- spaces
- alphabetic characters (from any language)
- no numbers
- no special characters (punctuation, symbols etc.)

The pattern I am currently using is `r'^[^\W\d]+$'` as suggested in [How to match alphabetical chars without numeric chars with Python regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673749/how-to-match-alphabetical-chars-without-numeric-chars-with-python-regexp). However it only seems to match like the pattern `r'^[a-zA-Z]+$`. That is, `Россия`, `Los Angeles` and `中国` do not match , only `Canada` does.

An example of my code:

```
import re
re.search(r'^[^\W\d]+$', 'Россия')
```

Which returns nothing.

Comment: Use `\u` instead of `\w`.

Comment: `s = re.search(r'^[\\u]+$','Россия')` still returns nothing. Using `\u` instead of `\\u` gives error _incomplete escape \u_.

Comment: Try `print(re.search(r'^[^\W\d]+$', 'Россия', re.UNICODE).group())`

Comment: `print(re.search(r'^[^\W\d]+$', 'Россия', re.UNICODE).group())` gives me an AttributeError: _NoneType object has no attribute 'group'_.

Comment: It [works here](http://ideone.com/3DejAg) (Python 3.4). Sorry, no idea :(

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your example works for me in Python 3.3 as well.  Are you sure you are running Python 3?

Comment: Why was the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works for me, but will find underscores and not spaces.  This works:

```
>>> re.search(r'^(?:[^\W\d_]| )+$', 'Los Angeles')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003C612A0>
>>> re.search(r'^(?:[^\W\d_]| )+$', 'Россия')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003A0D030>
>>> re.search(r'^(?:[^\W\d_]| )+$', 'Los_Angeles') # not found
>>> re.search(r'^(?:[^\W\d_]| )+$', '中国')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000003C612A0>
```