# Combine isalpha() and isspace() into 1 statement

Tags: python, string

I am looking for a function that combines the methods `isalpha()` and `isspace()` into a single method.
I want to check if a given string only contains letters and/or spaces, for example:

```
"This is text".isalpha_or_space()
# True
```

However, with the 2 methods, I get:

```
"This is text".isalpha() or "This is text".isspace()
# False
```

as the string is not only alpha nor space.

---

Of course, I could iterate over every character and check it for space or alpha.

I could also compare the string with `("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + " ")`

However, both of these approaches don't seem very pythonic to me - convince me otherwise.

Comment: Why not use a regular expression?

Comment: You can do `"This is text".replace(' ', '').isalpha()`, but regular expression is, well, more expressive

Comment: Regex is more expensive in python because it's not using a good algorithm. It's exponential in input and linear in the regexpr, when the algorithm that e.g. erlang and go uses by default is exponential in regexpr size and linear in the input size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most Pythonic will be to use a `def` for this:

```
def isalpha_or_space(self):
    if self == "":
        return False
    for char in self:
        if not (char.isalpha() or char.isspace()):
            return False
    return True
```

It is not easy to contribute this as a *method* on `str`, since Python does not encourage the monkeypatching of built-in types. My recommendation is just to leave this as a module level function.

Nonetheless, it is still possible to mimic the interface of a method, since most namespaces in Python are writable if you know where to find them. The suggestion below is not Pythonic, and relies on implementation detail.

```
>>> import gc
>>> def monkeypatch(type_, func): 
...     gc.get_referents(type_.__dict__)[0][func.__name__] = func 
...
>>> monkeypatch(str, isalpha_or_space)
>>> "hello world".isalpha_or_space()
True
```

Comment: You can simplify the `for` loop with `all`: `return all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in self)`

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regular expression (regex)](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto):

```
>>> import re
>>> result = re.match('[a-zA-Z\s]+$', "This is text")
>>> bool(result)
True
```

Breakdown:

- [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) - Python's regex module
- `[a-zA-Z\s]` - Any letter or whitespace
- `+` - One or more of the previous item
- `$` - End of string

---

The above works with ASCII letters. For the full Unicode range on Python 3, unfortunately the regex is a bit complicated:

```
>>> result = re.match('([^\W\d_]|\s)+$', 'un café')
```

Breakdown:

- `(x|y)` - *x* or *y*
- `[^\W\d_]` - Any [word character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-32) except a number or an underscore

*From [Mark Tolonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34959724/4518341) on [How to match all unicode alphabetic characters and spaces in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34957154/4518341)*

Comment: Fails for `n²`.

Comment: @wim Yeah, why wouldn't it? `²` is numeric

Comment: Because it *does* return a match, when it *shouldn't* - that's a failure, no?  Honestly I think you will never get this to work properly with a regex... but good luck  :)

Comment: @wim Oh, gotcha. Yeah I'm realizing `re` is not great for in-depth Unicode stuff like this. I think with the third-party [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module you could do `[\p{L}\s]` (any letter or any whitespace) and be done with it, but there might also be some niche whitespace I haven't thought of.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution:

```
s != '' and all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in s)
```

Comment: This returns the incorrect result for the empty string.

Comment: @wjandrea The most of answers at SO are different versions of one answer. The solution of wim (also mine) will error on falsy input like empty list, fo example.